# modify chrome extension to change window size

Tags: json, manifest, inspect

There's an extension that I use that alerts me to new mails and allows me to quickly compose mails. It's fine but if I could change one thing, it would be to make the 'compose message' window bigger. It's not big enough to display the 'to: ' textbox, let alone the textbox for the body

[image]
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiple-account-checker/dnimhgelcnggigekhdjlifjpndgmnglm

[image]

when I click the "compose new message" button, and the "compose message" window opens, I'd like it to always be a larger size. Does that make sense?!

If anyone knows how, and can explain to a novice, I'd be very grateful. So far I've JUST managed to get kittens compiled! (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) and have many ideas I'd can't stop thinking about! thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck? At getting the source code of the other extension or at actually modifying the window size? If you want to know how to view and edit other extensions' source code, see [How to modify an extension from the Chrome Web Store?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680682/how-to-modify-an-extension-from-the-chrome-web-store "How to modify an extension from the Chrome Web Store?")

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've already copied the original to a dev location and have the source code. I wanted to know if it was possible to trace what's happening, using the console or something (ctrl+shift+j in chrome) to hopefully take me to the "spawn window" function when I click compose... I inspected a few elements, hoped to trace what happens when the "compose" button is clicked... I've noticed now, however, that the popup is auto-sized, depended on the number of new mails, ie i.imgur.com/onGZ1vW.png

Comment: (i've added a whitebox for privacy) the pop-up is as large as it needs to be.. the "compose  message" windows is as large as the "new mails" popup that spawns it...

http://i.imgur.com/2PMPKqp.png



I would like to manually set the size of this window. I'd be happy with it remembering last position / size, or to "hard-code" it ...

does this make sense? I tried to follow the debugging tutorial (http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html) but can't complete step3 (If the Scripts button isn't already selected, click it) because I have no scripts button to click!

Comment: Going to inspect some other extensions to see how shortcut key activation is achieved, so copy into the amazing "lyrics for google chrome" extension (BEGGING for a shortcut key) thanks again

Comment: Debugging Gmail is not trivial (speaking from experience). I suggest to let that one go. WRT shortcut: You can declare a shortcut via the manifest file, see [`chrome.commands`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/commands.html) for more information.

Comment: UPDATE: I found the scripts section under dev.tools, please ignore that comment (it's under resources > frames > popup.html) 

This question is still open though! Any tips on modifying the multi-mail checker extension to MANUALLY set the "compose message" window size (so it isn't only as big as the popup window showing new messages, in case you want to compose a new message but have no new mail, see first image to illustrate) 

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-multi-account/mcpnehokodklgijkcakcfmccgpanipfp

THANKS!