# Edited Chrome Extension - chrome thinks it is malware

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently edited one of my extensions' css and HTML files to provide myself with a better experience.

However, When I went to enable the extension, a line right below the extension said "This extension may have been corrupted by malware.", and will not allow me to enable the extension itself.

How can I enable this extension?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Google's help page: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en.

It says to visit the extension page and click "repair" by the extension, but no such option appears for me.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out that I had to make a copy of the extension to an external directory, then delete the existing one.

From there, I followed the instructions here: https://superuser.com/questions/247651/how-does-one-install-an-extension-for-chrome-browser-from-the-local-file-system.

Text for the lazy:

> Navigate to chrome://extensions.
>
> Expand the developer dropdown menu and
>   click "Load Unpacked Extension".
>
> Navigate to local folder. Assuming
>   there are no errors, the extension should load into your browser.

Comment: Worked great. It had a folder called "_metadata" which is apparently reserved for the system and contained some hash verification numbers (which were obsolete after I edited the extension) I just deleted it and the copied extension folder loaded OK. I did not try, but maybe just deleting the _metadata from the original extension installation would have worked too.

Comment: I also ran into that issue myself, and I simply used `mv -rf folder_name new_folder_name`. That changes the folder to simply be "metadata" recursively. Also, you may run into issues with your version being set to 1 in your configuration file, so make sure to set that to two if the google compiler says that is your error.