# Publish google chrome extension in private

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

I want to publish chrome extension that is developed for my company. I have some doubts as follows:

1. Once I publish the extension, can I able to make changes in that after publishing?
2. After making changes, is it possible to update the user's extension who will be using it? or do they need to update it manually?

Comment: 1) yes 2) yes, the updates are automatic

Comment: Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680682/how-to-modify-an-extension-from-the-chrome-web-store

Comment: You can use "Visibility Option" - while publishing. This way your extension will not searchable but anyone with link can install/use it. This is useful to get early feedback on new extension.

Answer (score 0):

This post was helpful so I'm going to add some detail around publishing a chrome browser extension [using the private visibility](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/cws-dashboard-distribution/) setting

---

> Private: Only trusted testers can see it. You can change your trusted testers on your settings page.
> You can also include members of a Google Group that you own or manage.

[image: viability-private]