# How to enable "Allow access to file URLs" in google chrome to use some extensions on local files?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, local

I'm trying to use this extension [link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-designer-tools/jiiidpmjdakhbgkbdchmhmnfbdebfnhp) on my local file. But the option "Allow access to file URLs" is not available on the extension page. Is there any way for the extensions to work on local files?

Comment: That extension's manifest only has `*://*/*` which [allows only http/https schemes](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns), but not file. You can suggest the author to replace it with `<all_urls>`. Or you can download the extension, unpack, remove _metadata folder inside, and install it as a local extension (might wanna do it in Canary or you'll have to suppress the warning).

Comment: did exactly as you said now it works like a charm ty :)

Comment: @wOxxOm How can i unpack, remove _metadata folder inside, and install it as a local extension?

Comment: @PPP, [How to modify an extension from the Chrome Web Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16688027).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That extension's manifest only has `*://*/*` which allows only http/https schemes, but not file. You can suggest the author to replace it with `<all_urls>`. Or you can download the extension, unpack, remove _metadata folder inside, and install it as a local extension (might wanna do it in Canary or you'll have to suppress the warning). – [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)