# Editing a Chrome Extention

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

So i use [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-recorder/hniebljpgcogalllopnjokppmgbhaden) to record my online classes using a remote desktop .
it works perfect but when i stop my connection to the remote computer the recording stops.

i saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680682/how-to-modify-an-extension-from-the-chrome-web-store)
In this post the answer says to use the [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin)

i tried it but i couldn't wrap my head around the code.

one thing i found is that the extension sends a runtime message called "RECORDING_STOPPED" when recording ends and when i disconnect my remote desktop connection it apparently sends it that time also
i checked the /static/js/main.c502a7e6.js file Line : 16 , Column : 4875 as the line is quite long i didn't understand it

Comment: @Bravo The Chrome Source Viewer Mentioned In The Post i linked can be used in my case also so i thought i should link it , i edit the post to highlight the Chrome Source Viewer.

Comment: @Bravo /static/js/main.c502a7e6.js Line : 16 , Column : 4875

Comment: Yes i don't understand the code and came here in hopes of finding someone who does

Comment: Oh, so you need someone who understands the code - fair enough. I'm sure someone that understands javascript will be along shortly

Comment: So how remote desktop connections work is when i disconnect it sends sort of a logout / lock user type action and it is causing the extension to end the recording so i thought to change the code so it doesn't take that lock user / logout type action as indication to stop the recording.

Comment: Oh, right, RDP ... yeah, that may throw a spanner in the works, since RDP sessions tend to change a lot of underlying "devices" - so, you will find it's not feasible to keep recording when RDP session starts/stops

Comment: As you said "*i checked the /static/js/main.c502a7e6.js file Line : 16 , Column : 4875 as the line is quite long i didn't understand it*"

It means the extension was developed by some javascript bundler and they minify the code, so it is really hard to understand. you have to find its github repository (if it has one) there will be all the original source code.

Comment: @Bravo "so, you will find it's not feasible to keep recording when RDP session starts/stops " This is not the case i have tested a handful of recording extensions they do record amidst the session starting and stopping but the problem with them was either the video was too large of a file which is unseekable where the extension i mentioned in post gives a usable size of video and they are seekable so i thought of trying to fix the code in this extension rather than moving to another one.