# How can I change the functionality and appearance of the back button in Chrome with an extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I'm thinking about creating a Chrome extension that modifies the behavior of the back button. I'd like to be able to change the color of the back button, modify the drop-down menu that appears when you right-click it, and allow that right-click menu to appear when it is grayed out.

Is this possible? I'm under the impression that it isn't for security reasons, but I haven't been able to find much on the web about this.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But a more efficient way of doing it is to download a chrome theme extension of your taste go to its `.CRX` file and modify it. Here is a answer that might help     
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16680682/how-to-modify-an-extension-from-the-chrome-web-store

Comment: @RKazmi Thank you for your response. Unfortunately I need to create an extension that adds additional functionality to the back button rather than just changes the aesthetics. I've read through the chrome.webNavigation API page and couldn't find functions that actually modify the back button.