# Prevent tab discarding

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, microsoft-edge-extension

Is there a way prevent tab from discarding without reloading when used

```
chrome.tabs.discard(tabId);
```

?

I have 2 extensions, one that discards tabs and second that manages it's own single tab and I need second extension protect it's tab from being discarded.
My current work around is to listen on [`chrome.tabs.onReplaced`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#event-onReplaced) event and reload the tab:

```
chrome.tabs.onReplaced.addListener((newTabId, oldTabId) =>
{
  chrome.tabs.reload(newTabId);
});
```

But is there a way ***undiscard*** a tab without reloading it, or better yet prevent discard in the first place?

Comment: Chrome simply reloads the tab when it's clicked, there's no "undiscard". The only way to prevent discarding is to [modify that other extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16688027).

Comment: You can try `chrome.tabs.update(id, { autoDiscardable: false })` to prevent being discarded. For more information, please read [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-update).

Comment: @wOxxOm this seems not to be the case, when I "proactively discard" a tab via chrome://discards/, if I then manually select the tab, all values in edit fields are preserved and the HTML is not reloaded. However if I do a `chrome.tabs.reload`, the HTML is reloaded and the values in edit fields is lost.

Comment: Someone should report that undiscard is necessary in https://crbug.com explaining the difference.