# How to activate a discarded Chromium tab from an extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Our extension needs to be able to activate tabs, it does so using [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs#method-update):

```js
    chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { active: true });
```

When the tab in question is [`discarded`](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/tab-discarding), this does not cause the tab to render, there is a blank page instead. The properties of the tab after doing so are (irrelevent properties ommited):

```json
{
    active: true,
    autoDiscardable: true,
    discarded: true,
    highlighted: true,
    selected: true,
    status: "unloaded",
}
```

After searching around I found a [comment on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73202088/prevent-tab-discarding) that said:

> Chrome simply reloads the tab when it's clicked, there's no "undiscard".

However this does not seem to exactly be the case. Consider the following simple HTML

```html
    <h1 id="time"></h1>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('time').textContent = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
    </script>
    <input />
```

Load the page and set some value in the input field, then discard the tab by clicking *Proactive Discard* on chrome://discards/.

- After reactivating the tab manually, the timestamp is recreated but the `input` value remains.
  [image: manual activate]
- After activating by running:
  `chrome.tabs.query({ index: 0 }, tabs => chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { active: true}))`
  the screen is blank (until manually activated).
  [image: Just tabs.update]
- After activating **and** reloading by running:
  `chrome.tabs.query({ index: 0 }, tabs => chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, { active: true}, tab => chrome.tabs.reload(tab.id)))`
  the page is reloaded, timestamp is new and the `input` value is lost.
  [image: update and reload]

My question (at long last), how do I "undiscard" (*rescard*?) a discarded tab programmatically while maintaining the state of the page?

Comment: Since there's no such API you can try a workaround like calling chrome.tabs.sendMessage or executeScript. You can suggest implementing an explicit API in https://crbug.com or in [WECG](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/issues/).

Comment: Thanks, I've created https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1519123 I hope I filled in the right details.